# Seaside still actively developed?

Tags: smalltalk, seaside

Just a quick question. Since the last major version of seaside came out in 2010, is it still being actively developed? There doesn't seem to be too much going on at the moment. Also Iliad seems kinda dead.

Thx,
Henrik

Comment: Also see [Is Seaside still a valid option?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199149/is-seaside-still-a-valid-option/3201005) for a slightly older discussion about the state of Seaside.

Comment: I've read that, but it seemed kinda long ago - yet very interesting!

Comment: I've been checking out Seaside for the past few months. What I've noticed is a much smaller community, and much less talk about it on the web, but the community is very helpful and quick to answer questions, so I consider that is still in active use. Great to hear about future development too (below).

Answer (score 5):

Seaside is a very stable and extensible framework. Although no major changes have been applied during the last couple of years, we are creating highly dynamic web applications with it without ever being limited by Seaside itself.

And a [3.1 release](http://code.google.com/p/seaside/wiki/Seaside310Changelog) is upcoming.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Seaside is still actively developed. Currently, Seaside 3.1 is in the making.

Answer (score 3):

Iliad seems kinda dead, but it's not ;)

Thing is there's a **very** small community behind it, but if you check the repositories, you'll see there are very recent commits.

I'm guessing there's going to be a new release soon this year.

- SmalltalkHub repository:
  http://smalltalkhub.com/#!/~Objectfusion/Iliad/
- Squeaksource repository: http://www.squeaksource.com/IliadDev.html

I've been using it for all web applications I've coded since 2010, and although the entry path may be a bit steep (not much documentation, not much real-world code to look at, tiny community, etc) I'd say its easiness and simplicity really pay off in the mid-term.